# JavaCV Video Player with FFmpeg and JavaFx

Tags: java, javafx, ffmpeg, javacv

I want to create a media player using Java CV, but I can not adjust the frame rate
And because of this, some videos play fast and some play slow

Is it possible to read the information of a video through a FFmpegFrameGrraber object and set it in another object to solve the problem?
Of course, I did this and did not get an answer, but if there is another way, please help

```
playThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    final String videoFilename = "E:\\Java\\s1\\3.mp4";
                    final String videoFilename2 = "E:AudioVideo.mp4";
                    final String videoFilename3 = "E:\\1.mp4";
                    final String videoFilename4 = "E:\\Java\\s1\\3.mp4";


                     FFmpegFrameGrabber grabber = new FFmpegFrameGrabber(videoFilename);



                    grabber.start();

                    grabber.setFrameRate(30.00);


                    primaryStage.setWidth(grabber.getImageWidth());
                    primaryStage.setHeight(grabber.getImageHeight());

                    final AudioFormat audioFormat = new AudioFormat(grabber.getSampleRate(), 16, grabber.getAudioChannels(), true, true);

                    final DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(SourceDataLine.class, audioFormat);
                    final SourceDataLine soundLine = (SourceDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
                    soundLine.open(audioFormat);
                    soundLine.start();

                    JavaFXFrameConverter converter = new JavaFXFrameConverter();

                    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

                    while (!Thread.interrupted()) {
                        Frame frame = grabber.grab();
                        if (frame == null) {
                            break;
                        }
                        if (frame.image != null) {
                            final Image image = converter.convert(frame);//
                            Platform.runLater(() -> {
                                
                                imageView.setImage(image);

                            });
                        }
                         else if (frame.samples != null) {
                            final ShortBuffer channelSamplesShortBuffer = (ShortBuffer) frame.samples[0];
                            channelSamplesShortBuffer.rewind();

                            final ByteBuffer outBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(channelSamplesShortBuffer.capacity() * 2);

                            for (int i = 0; i < channelSamplesShortBuffer.capacity(); i++) {
                                short val = channelSamplesShortBuffer.get(i);
                                outBuffer.putShort(val);
                            }

                            try {



                                executor.execute(() -> {
                                    soundLine.write(outBuffer.array(), 0, outBuffer.capacity());
                                    outBuffer.clear();
                                });
                            } catch (Exception interruptedException) {
                                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                            }
                        }

                    }
                    executor.shutdownNow();
                    executor.awaitTermination(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

                    soundLine.stop();
                    grabber.stop();
                    grabber.release();
                    Platform.exit();
                } catch (Exception exception) {
                    LOG.log(Level.SEVERE, null, exception);
                    System.exit(1);
                }
            }
        });
        playThread.start();
    }
```

Comment: yes using this library you can get video information using ffprobe commands

https://github.com/tanersener/ffmpeg-kit

Comment: Try to call grabAtFrameRate() instead of just grab().